# In VB code, how do I call listboxes using String array

Tags: vb.net, listbox, controls

Here is my String array with a list of listbox names...

```
Public ListOfBoxes As String() = {"lstWords02", "lstWords03", "lstWords04", "lstWords05", _
                                  "lstWords06", "lstWords07", "lstWords08", "lstWords09", _
                                  "lstWords10", "lstWords11", "lstWords12", "lstWords13", _
                                  "lstWords14", "lstWords15", "lstWords16", "lstWords17", _
                                  "lstWords18"}
```

I would like to loop through each of the ***listboxes*** and  run some code.   my attempt below fails because lbx is a ***string***, not a ***listbox***.

```
       For Each lbx As String In ListOfBoxes
           lbx.Items.Add(SomeStringVariable)
       Next
```

Any Ideas?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  -Cam

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name of the listboxes directly in the array like this.

```
Public ListOfBoxes As ListBox() = {lstWords02, lstWords03, lstWords04, lstWords05}
```

Then loop over the array like this

```
For Each lbx As ListBox In ListOfBoxes
   lbx.Items.Add(SomeStringVariable)   
Next
```

If you still want to use the names of the listboxes, try this

```
Public ListOfBoxes As String = {"lstWords02", "lstWords03", "lstWords04", "lstWords05"}

For Each item As String In ListOfBoxes
    Ctype(Controls.Find(item, True)(0), ListBox).Items.Add(SomeStringVariable)
Next
```

`Controls.Find` returns an array of all the controls with the specified name. In the example I gave above, I assumed each control on the form has unique names. You can adjust the code as per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
by your ref code "lbx.Items.Add(SomeStringVariable)" is using for add item in list.




Public ListOfBoxes As String() = {"lstWords02", "lstWords03", "lstWords04", "lstWords05", _
                                          "lstWords06", "lstWords07", "lstWords08", "lstWords09", _
                                          "lstWords10", "lstWords11", "lstWords12", "lstWords13", _
                                          "lstWords14", "lstWords15", "lstWords16", "lstWords17", _
                                          "lstWords18"}
  For Each lbx As String In ListOfBoxes
            Listbox.Items.Add(lbx)
        Next
```

Comment: In your For Each you are referring to the class ListBox. You need an instance of the class to refer to. The OP doesn't want to add the names of list boxes to some other list box. This code doesn't make much sense.